# Count the number of occurrences of a given item in a (sorted) list?

Tags: python

I'm asked to create a method that returns the number of occurrences of a given item in a list. I know how to write code to find a specific item, but how can I code it to where it counts the number of occurrences of a random item.

For example if I have a `list [4, 6 4, 3, 6, 4, 9]` and I type something like

`s1.count(4)`, it should `return 3` or  `s1.count(6)` should `return 2`.

I'm not allowed to use and built-in functions though.

In a recent assignment, I was asked to count the number of occurrences that `sub string` "ou" appeared in a given string, and I coded it

```
if len(astr) < 2:
    return 0
else:
    return (astr[:2] == "ou")+ count_pattern(astr[1:])
```

Would something like this work??

```
def count(self, item):
    num=0
    for i in self.s_list:
        if i in self.s_list:
            num[i] +=1
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.s_list)
```

Comment: `num` is a number, so `num[i]` will not work. Also there is no sense in iterating over the list (`for i in self.s_list`) and the test whether the element is in the list (`if i in self.s_list`). This will always be the case. The approach (looping and `num[i] +=1
`) is good though, if you correct it and use the right data type.

Comment: +1 Finally: A good homework question, and correctly tagged.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to use the <code> format when adding a comment.. What i have doesn't quite work the way that i need it to..def count(self, item):
        num=0
        if item in self.s_list:
            num +=1
        return num

Comment: @WillS To format code in comments, [use backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). You're really close, you'll just have to recheck the `if`. Hint: If `item` is `4`, what would you want to check?

Comment: Not sure what it is that you're asking me.. If item is 4, i'd want to check how many 4's are in the list. May a for loop inside the if?

Comment: For reference, the correct check would be checking whether `i` in the loop is 4. Therefore, the `if` statement should be `if i == item:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this list is already sorted, the "most efficient" method -- in terms of Big-O -- would be to perform a binary search with a count-forward/count-backward if the value was found.

However, for an *unsorted* list as in the example, then the only way to count the occurrences is to go through each item in turn (or sort it first ;-). Here is some pseudo-code, note that it is *simpler* than the code presented in the original post (there is no `if x in list` or `count[x]`):

```
set count to 0
for each element in the list:
   if the element is what we are looking for:
      add one to count
```

Happy coding.

Comment: The pseudocode is eerily close to Python code, but you did a great job obfuscating it so that it's **not** valid Python code.

Comment: That's probably because *Python* is eerily close to being pseudocode.

Comment: I concur.  Linear search on unsorted data will be O(n).  Sorting it will be O(n lg n) and then searching it O(lg n) = O(n lg n).

Comment: Posted a more efficient Big-O method

Answer (score 2):

If I told you to count the number of fours in the following list, how would *you* do it?

```
1 4 2 4 3 8 2 1 4 2 4 9 7 4
```

You would start by remembering `no fours yet`, and add 1 for each element that equals 4. To traverse a list, you can use a [`for` statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Given an element of the list `el`, you can check whether it is four like this:

```
if el == 4:
  # TODO: Add 1 to the counter here
```

---

In response to your edit:

You're currently testing `if i in self.s_list:`, which doesn't make any sense since `i` is an element of the list and therefore always present in it.

When adding to a number, you simply write `num += 1`. Brackets are only necessary if you want to access the values of a list or dictionary.

Also, don't forget to `return num` at the end of the function so that somebody calling it gets the result back.

Comment: Given the example code, I think the OP knows how `if` works :)

Comment: @larsmans I wrote the answer before he posted the whole code, and - lo and behold - the problem of his current version is in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the most efficient method in terms of Big-O would be O(log n). @pst's method would result in O(log n + s) which could become linear if the array is made up of equal elements.

The way to achieve O(log n) would be to use 2 binary searches (which gives O(2log n), but we discard constants, so it is still O(log n)) that are modified to not have an equality test, therefore making all searches unsuccessful. However, on an unsuccessful search (low > high) we return low.

In the first search, if the middle is greater than your search term, recurse into the higher part of the array, else recurse into the lower part. In the second search, reverse the binary comparison.

The first search yields the right boundary of the equal element and the second search yields the left boundary. Simply subtract to get the amount of occurrences. 
Based on algorithm described in Skiena.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework... anyways. Try `list.count(item)`. That should do the job.

Third or fourth element here:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Edit:

try something else like:

```
bukket = dict()
for elem in astr:
    if elem not in bukket.keys():
        bukket[elem] = 1
    else:
        bukket[elem] += 1
```

You can now get all the elements in the list with dict.keys() as list and the corresponding occurences with dict[key].

So you can test it:

```
import random

l = []

for i in range(0,200):
    l.append(random.randint(0,20))

print l
l.sort()
print l

bukket = dict()
for elem in l:
    if elem not in bukket.keys():
        bukket[elem] = 1
    else:
        bukket[elem] += 1


print bukket
```

Comment: Not allowed to use any built in list functions

Comment: This question is *tagged* as homework, by the OP. And he explicitely mentions that he can't use the built-in `count` function.

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot to read the tags. Shappens. I edited my solution so you can have a pretty (imho) slick version of this. It doesn't care about knowing the elements before and it doesn't care about what they are. Works for me pretty fine everytime I use it. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @FlorianH. The OP wants just to count one value. By the way, you're reinventing [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and the `sort` is unnecessary. Your answer can be written shorter as `print Collections.counter(random.randint(0,20) for i in range(200))`.

Comment: You can easily get the count of one item by callint bukket[item], although I admit, that this creates a bit of an overhead. But you also get a list of all other items. Also, my answer was meant as an example  of usage. I am very well aware that Collections.counter would do the same job. But since he may not use any list function, I concluded that Collections aso. would also be bad. Since he postulated a sorted list, I included a sort too. To make it easier to understand.